# Find whether Number is between two numbers

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, int, range

I have an array of numbers 0,1,2,3,4,5,6
the starting index and ending index is passed randomly. I have to find whether the given number is between the starting index and ending index, 
For example, if the starting index is 0 and ending index is 3, I will need to tell whether a given number is either 0,1,2 or 3 and return false if it is 4,5 and 6.
Now the tricky part for me
In in case if starting index is 4 and ending index is 1 then i need to tell whether the number is either 4,5,6,0 or 1 and return false if its 2 and 3

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter array items with `.filter()` first and then use `.includes()` to check for existence:

```js
let data = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

let checker = (arr, start, end, value) => (
    start <= end ?
    arr.filter((_, i) => i >= start && i <= end) :
    arr.filter((_, i) => i >= start || i <= end)
).includes(value);

console.log(checker(data, 0, 3, 1));
console.log(checker(data, 0, 3, 4));
console.log(checker(data, 4, 1, 5));
console.log(checker(data, 4, 1, 2));
console.log(checker(data, 4, 1, 1));
```